# AWS Glue- Unable to Connect Glue Data Catalog from Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new beginner and trying to learn AWS Glue using Pyspark data frames . Please help me out in resolving the below issue

I have setup the local Windows 10 environment to run the Glue Scripts and followed the below steps
Installed Docker Desktop
Setup Docker Image and created container and able to run scripts in Jupyter Notebook (http://localhost:8888/tree?)

I am working on scenario to "extract data from S3 and my target is S3 and transformations using PySpark in AWS Glue."

```
    import sys
    import datetime
    import json
    from collections import Iterable, OrderedDict
    from itertools import product
    import logging
    import boto3
    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column
    from pyspark.sql.types import array, ArrayType, IntegerType, NullType, StringType, StructType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, collect_list, explode, lit, split, when, upper
    from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
    from awsglue.transforms import Relationalize
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    from awsglue.job import Job
    from awsglue.transforms import *
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    start_dttm=datetime.datetime.now()
    print(start_dttm)
    print("Job Execution Started…")
    
    #### I have created database named testonly and table named mytable in Data  Catalog in the AWS Console 
    
    ds = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "testonly", table_name = "mytable", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

While I am trying to connect to the database using the above statement , I am getting an huge error

```
Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-963ee7d058bb> in <module>
----> 1 ds = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "testonly", table_name = "mytable", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

/home/aws-glue-libs/awsglue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py in from_catalog(self, database, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)
    623             raise Exception("Parameter table_name is missing.")

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.getCatalogSource.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load region information from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.EndpointConfig$.getConfig(EndpointConfig.scala:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.AWSConnectionUtils$.<init>(AWSConnectionUtils.scala:36)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.AWSConnectionUtils$.<clinit>(AWSConnectionUtils.scala)
```